# It is possible deleting Skeleton small branches in opencv or scikit image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology, scikit-image

Is it possibile deleting small branches during skeleton procedure?

As in this picture:
http://felix.abecassis.me/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/skel_opencv.png

Only O letter is perfect but not all the others letters.

THere is a way during the procedure or after to deleting this little branches?
I use python opencv, but a solution also with pymorph or scikit-image is good.
Here there is the code i used for skeletonization:
[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135676/problems-during-skeletonization-image-for-extracting-contours)

Original image: http://felix.abecassis.me/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/opencv.png

Answer (score 4):

Here is the result from [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org):

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import morphology

image = io.imread('opencv.png')
out = morphology.skeletonize(image > 0)
```

[image: skimage-skeleton]

Comment: are you sure? I have only a total black image!I tried with both images; not skeletonized and skeletonized.

Comment: Skeletonize returns an image with zeros and ones, but the dtype should probably be bool or float, not int (I've opened a ticket: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/489).  In the meantime, just use ``out = out.astype(float)``.

Comment: Do you have any implementation of this in C++ instead of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Scikit image has skeletonize and thin that may help accomplish what you want.

The lee version of skeletonize effectively does more thinning of fringe skeleton features than skeleton alone.

Thin gives you the ability to partially skeletonize the image.  You can do a partial thin followed by a dilate or open operation to get something close to a morphological prune (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruning_(morphology)).

There are examples of the scikit skeleton tools here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html

```
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.util import invert

# Invert the horse image
image = invert(data.horse())

# perform skeletonization
skeleton = skeletonize(image)
skeleton_lee = skeletonize(image, method='lee')

# display results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 4),
                         sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[0].set_title('original', fontsize=20)

ax[1].imshow(skeleton, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].set_title('skeleton', fontsize=20)

ax[2].imshow(skeleton_lee, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[2].axis('off')
ax[2].set_title('skeleton lee', fontsize=20)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]